# How to turn off 'yarn develop'?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I've started using yarn (I'm a rookie if you can't tell), and after running the command

`yarn develop`

in my terminal (via VSCode), I have no idea how to stop the localhost:8000. Is there an opposite command to `yarn develop`? If so, what is it? If not, what's the best way to go about restarting/stopping the localhost?

Could anyone please help me with this?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: ctrl+c stops processes in your terminal.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal where you`ve ran `yarn develop` hit `ctrl-c` and it will stop running. Also you can see the list of available scripts in your `package.json` under `scripts` parameter

Comment: Thank you very much! I got really confused when I tried to Google this - maybe I've gone a bit too deep, haha.